# "Checking browser before accessing..." error when using Curl

Tags: php, html, parsing, curl

I am trying to use curl to get the contents off a website. The error that I am getting is.

> **"Checking your browser before accessing roosterteeth.com"**

I tried changing different attributes in curl but still no luck. I have tried using **PHP Simple HTML Dom Parser** but once again no luck.

below is my current code.

```
<?php
$divContents = array();
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0';
$html = curl_init("http://roosterteeth.com/home.php");
curl_setopt($html, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($html, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($html, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($html, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$content = curl_exec($html);
foreach($content->find("div.streamIndividual") as $div) {
$divContents[] = $div->outertext; }
file_put_contents("cache.htm", implode(PHP_EOL, $divContents));
$hash = file_get_contents("pg_1_hash.htm");
$cache = file_get_contents("cache.htm");
if ($hash == ($pageHash = md5($test))) {
} else {
$fpa = fopen("pg_1.htm", "w");
fwrite($fpa, $cache);
fclose($fpa);
$fpb = fopen("pg_1_hash.htm", "w");
fwrite($fpb, $pageHash);
fclose($fpb);
}
?>
```

As it stands the code above shows a different error due to the **find** command not being able to get any content. The code below shows the error I get from the site.

```
<?php
$divContents = array();
$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0';
$html = curl_init("http://roosterteeth.com/home.php");
curl_setopt($html, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($html, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($html, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent);
curl_setopt($html, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$content = curl_exec($html);
echo $content;
?>
```

My hunch about the error is that the server thinks that I am a bot (which I don't blame it to believe that). I used curl to see if i can pretend to be a client and bypass the checker but was unsuccessful. I hope someone can shed some light onto this.

For a visual error click this [link.](http://zambretta.uk/php/rt_news/pg-1-proxy.php)

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: The site check for cookies, if it's not exists, set cookies and redirect the browser.... you need to activate cookies for CURL transfer. But it looks the cookies will be set by javascript...

Answer (score -1):

If the site you're trying to access uses wordpress, it's definetly has security issues. It' a known malicious modification for WP and redirects users to some different sites. So in this case the problem is not in your code.